# How do I compute the action of the Frobenius on the torsion of the Jacobian in Sage?

Tags: algebraic-curves, sagemath, etale-cohomology

I have a curve $C/\mathbb F_q$ and I would like to compute the eigenvalues of the Frobenius action on $H^1(C,\mathbb Z/\ell)$. One way would be to compute the integral Frobenius action and reduce mod $\ell$ but surely there is a much faster way?

I am having a difficult time searching the documentation for this.

Comment: Tip: provide code that creates a toy example.